# How to make a custom theme with plugins in WordPress?

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

I have created my own theme in WordPress. In that theme i'm using other plugins ( jQuery Photo slider ). Now I want to use this theme for a different website. Can i save plugins with the theme? First off, is this even possible?

This is my first attempt in WordPress.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are not allowed to add plugins along with your theme, but you can always send a readme along with the theme, telling the user what plugins you want them to use, or you could just zip the plugins located in the plugin folder and make that as a custom extra choice to apply when using your theme.